# Converting accelerating linear motion into constant rotational motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

Suppose there is an accelerating mass along a straight line, and you would want to convert that linear motion into rotary motion. Is it possible to convert that accelerating linear motion into constant speed rotary motion? Could you suggest mechanisms that I can use?

Comment: What sort of application are you thinking about?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just wanted to know if it's possible.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking. A constantly *accelerating* linear motion into a constant *velocity* rotation? Maybe you're trying to be clever and want "tie it to a pole", but the constant acceleration of a rotating particle is orthogonal to its velocity. Other than that, I don't think it's possible to get a constant, nonzero value to equate to its time derivative.

Comment: @user1478061, Anything is possible. The question is it practical. Explain the engineering problem you are need help, we will try to guide you.

Comment: There may be a good, constructive question in here but at the moment it's not clear what specific question you're seeking to have answered.  I have put your question on-hold so you can [edit] and focus your question without invalidating any other answers.

Comment: A cable wound on a tapered drum would accomplish this for a finite amount of time. This technique has historically been used in reverse to slow stunt-people when jumping off of buildings. I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean
ACCELERATING linear  to
CONSTANT rotary motion?

1. A variable ratio drive as in the DAF cone drive now used in a number of Japanese gearboxes would work.
2. Provided the accelerating linear motion is repeatable and predictable, below one turn this can be seen as a "cam".
   The linear motion is coupled to the cam surface where cam radius from centre decreases in inverse ratio to the linear velocity.
   For more than one turn the cam becomes a conic surface with again a radius proportional to inverse of velocity as the linear drive accelerates. This becomes impractical for large variations of linear velocity.
3. Add electronics in the middle and it becomes an alternator-motor set.